# How to properly index strings for lookup and excepts, the PostgreSQL way

Tags: postgresql

Due to infrastructure costs, I've been studying the possibility to migrate a few databases to PostgreSQL. So far I am loving it. But there are a few topics I am quite lost. I need some guidance on one of them.

I have an ETL process that queries "deltas" in my database and imports the new data. To do so, I use lookup tables that store hashbytes of some strings to facilitate the lookup. This works in SQL Server, but apparently things work quite differently in PostgreSQL. In SQL Server, using hashbytes + except is suggested when working with millions of rows.

Let's suppose the following table

```
+----+-------+------------------------------------------+
| Id | Name  |                hash_Name                 |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Mark  | 31e9697d43a1a66f2e45db652019fb9a6216df22 |
|  2 | Pablo | ce7169ba6c7dea1ca07fdbff5bd508d4bb3e5832 |
|  3 | Mark  | 31e9697d43a1a66f2e45db652019fb9a6216df22 |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

And my lookup table

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                hash_Name                 |
+------------------------------------------+
| 31e9697d43a1a66f2e45db652019fb9a6216df22 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

When querying new data (Pablo's hash), I can advance from the simplified query bellow:

```sql
SELECT hash_name 
FROM   mytable 
EXCEPT 
SELECT hash_name 
FROM   mylookup
```

Thinking the PostgreSQL way, how could I achieve this? Should I index and use EXCEPT? Or is there a better way of doing so?

From my research, I couldn't find much regarding storing hashbytes. Apparently, it is a matter of creating indexes and choosing the right index for the job. More precisely: BTREE for single field indexes and GIN for multiple field indexes.

Comment: You are most probably better off with an [anti-join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f0d06/2), but if `mylookup` table is much smaller than `mytable` then Postgres will probably never use any index for such kind of query (it realizes that almost all of the `mylookup` rows are needed in the output, so a sequential scan will be performed). -- Could you please give more details why did you choose to use these "hashes"?

Comment: Ty, @pozs! I chose to use hashbytes in SQL Server since my hashed column is a string and hashbytes are best for indexing, lookups and column comparison. Since I will be working with millions of rows, I need to optimize it. Example: http://bidn.com/blogs/TomLannen/bidn-blog/2265/using-hashbytes-to-compare-columns